# Using the Back button in a webview in Android

Tags: android, webview, back-button

When using the normal mobile browser, when you press the Back button, it takes you to the previous page. When a WebView is used in my app to display a web page and the user wants to return to the previous page, how is typically done? Does pressing the Back button automatically take the user back to the previous page or does it take them back to the previous Activity? I would assume that since the Back button is normally meant to take the user to the previous activity, it shouldn't be used to return to a previous web page. If this is the case, should my mobile web page include its own Back link that a user clicks on?

I guess what I am trying to do is to understand the correct behavior I should be employing.

Comment: Just IMO, it would be better (under the Principle of Least Surprise) to go to the previous web page; this is what the Android stock browser does (on my 2.1 phone, anyway), so the user will expect that.

Comment: But if the user normally expects the Back button to take them to the previous activity, would that not be abnormal behavior?

Comment: Depends. When I'm in an Android web browser, *I* expect the back button to take me back a webpage.

Comment: But that's probably because there is no previous activity, so the behavior you would be expecting is probably correct. But this probably isn't the case with a webview embedded in an app.

Comment: The stock browser does have no previous activity to go back to; however, I still think it would be better to go back a webpage on a Back button press. (Feel free to disregard this opinion.)

Comment: If that were the case, how would you allow the user to return to the previous activity in your app?

Comment: The stock browser "goes to the previous activity" (i.e. exits) when there are no more pages to go back to. Perhaps try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please keep in mind that back buttons is coming with majority of the android devices. So you do not need a back button in your activity to go back to previous activity.

And about the webview if you want navigation in the webview to travel all the previous pages then you can put a back button and implement the navigation of the webview using the method `webview.goBack()`.

In short, If you want your user to navigate to previous page then you should give functionality of the webview to go back to previous page and from the first page user click on back button again finish the activity.

Comment: I was actually thinking of having a Back button as part of the web page content, but your solution is better by using a Button control and using that to navigate backwards instead. This still allows the user to use the hardware Back button to return to the previous activity.

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at some popular browser. currently, in my device, there are two browsers

1. chrome
2. default internet browser

In both browsers, it goes to the previous page. So it is a common behavior. to do so

you can overwrite the `onBackPressed` to go to your previous page.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
            if(mWebView.canGoBack() == true){
                mWebView.goBack();
            }
            else{
                finish();
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't asking *how* to implement the Back button. I was looking to understand whether it should be used to go to the previous page or previous activity.

Comment: I see no harm there to implement back page navigation by using back button. As there are plenty of browser which do that

Comment: But we're not talking about a browser. We're talking about a WebView that is embedded in an app where the normal behavior of the Back button is to take the user to the previous activity. In my app, the user will open up the WebView in a separate activity and probably assumes that the Back button takes them to my app's previous activity. There has to be a clear way of returning to the previous activity. So I'm beginning to think that using the Back button for web page navigation is a bad thing.

Comment: It definitely depends on your application purpose.. There is no fixed standards for that

Answer (score 1):

You can use this override the onkeydown event and check the key pressed (in this case is back key) and check if is there any previous page

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(yourWebView.canGoBack() == true){
                    yourWebView.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: See my comment to StinePike.

Answer (score 0):

When you are clicking back button, you are clicking it for activity that is opening the webview better thing would be to give a back button in you layout..and hence saving the last url opened by user

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying to use the Back button to return to the previous activity or previous web page?

Comment: to go back just save the last opened URL and open that URL on back button press hence user will feel he is redirecting on back page.

Comment: That's not what I am asking. Read the question again. I am looking for the correct behavior that the user expects and not a coding solution.

Comment: does it take them back to the previous Activity?
YES it is taking them back to previous activity as every activity has a layout linked and normally when you click on back button last activity is called not webview's last opened page

Comment: Oh that's interesting. Are you saying that if I launch an activity with a WebView and immediately press the Back button, it will return me to the previous activity BUT if I navigate to a different page in the WebView and then use the Back button, it takes me to the previous page? If that is the case, that could be bad since a user could never return to the previous activity until they return to the first page that was displayed in the WebView.

Comment: That depends on you logic part if there is no URL to go back then user must exit the app or go to previous activity otherwise he must redirected to previous page by using code that have been mentioned in comments above by @NAYOSO

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in activity with WebView:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if(yourWebView.canGoBack() == true){
                yourWebView.goBack();
            }else{
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

or override onBackPressed method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   if(yourWebView.canGoBack() == true){
      yourWebView.goBack();
   } else {
      finish();
   }
}
```