# How to differentiate between a back button press within an Android webview and a back button press taking you to a separate page?

Tags: android, webview, back-button

I would like to send a metric if my back button press took me to a different page within the same WebView or a different metric if it exited the WebView. How would I do that?

In other words, I would like to know if the new page that comes up after hitting the back button is an instance of the same webview or a different fragment in the same activity.

Comment: read handling page navigation @ http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the Back button in a webview in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051870/using-the-back-button-in-a-webview-in-android)